# How can i destructure object which will point to global constant?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following method in my typescript file

```
 this.userService.getUserById(this.userId).subscribe((user: any) => {
        
 });
```

if i want to get for example the property salary from the user i could write

```
 this.userService.getUserById(this.userId).subscribe((user: any) => {
    const salary = this.user.salary;    
 });
```

or with object destructuring  - shorter syntax

```
 this.userService.getUserById(this.userId).subscribe((user: any) => {
    const {salary} = user;    
 });
```

but i need this salary not to be local variable - but global in my `user component file in angular`
 `user.component.ts`

i can to that with assaignment directly

```
 this.userService.getUserById(this.userId).subscribe((user: any) => {
    this.salary = user.salary;   
 });
```

but i can't find a way to do that with OBJECTT DESTRUCTURING

if i do

```
 const {this.salary} = user;
```

or

```
 {this.salary} = user;
```

it does not work

Comment: there's no way to do it with destructuring. Destructuring is merely syntactic sugar over variable declaration and assignment

Comment: Your second and third sets of code are not equivalent because you use `this.user` in the second...

Comment: Also, work on making your code readable and maintainable, not clever.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.userService.getUserById(this.userId).subscribe(({salary}: any) => {
   this.salary = salary;   
});
```

Or

```
 this.userService.getUserById(this.userId).subscribe(({salary}: any) => this.salary = salary)
```

Destructing syntax is to get property from your object. If you really want you can do it via `var` instead of `const` but it is not recommended.

You can also make something like this:

```js
const obj = {
  a: '1',
  b: '2',
  c: {
    d: '4',
    e: ['5', '6', '7']
  },
  f: '8',
  g: '9',
  h: '10'
}

const {a,b: customName,c: {d,e: [first, ...restArr] }, ...restObj} = obj;

// console.log(b) error
// console.log(c) error
// console.log(e) error
// console.log(f) error
// console.log(g) error
// console.log(h) error
console.log(a,customName,d, first);
console.log(restArr);
console.log(restObj);
```